# Using both Java and Python with the new "Module" feature on AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine

Is it possible to create a Google AppEngine application using Java in one module and Python in another (or Go)?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but since even on different versions you could do it and it seems to be just another namespace for providing stats and billing I wouldn't see the reason why it would not support it, unless the language doesn't support modules yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to have modules with different languages. I have not tried it myself but it has been [confirmed](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/1228g7-qXZY/_ubjgHlE2_wJ) in the GAE google group when SDK 1.8.2 was first released.