# can i serve PHP and python on a single project in app engine?

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine

Can I serve PHP and python on a single project in app engine?
for example 
/php/* will run php code, but the root / will run python code.

Comment: You can use modules: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382955/using-both-java-and-python-with-the-new-module-feature-on-appengine

Answer (score 0):

You can (and many do) use a front-end like nginx or Apache that handles and forwards different paths differently. I do not see why you would want your application engine to be "bilingual" though.