# Run both Java and PHP on google app engine project

Tags: java, php, google-app-engine

I'm building a java project on google app engine platform,
and I found a PHP library that will help me on my project needs.

is it possible to run both projects under the same app engine project?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use different languages in different modules.

See [Using both Java and Python with the new "Module" feature on AppEngine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382955/using-both-java-and-python-with-the-new-module-feature-on-appengine)